# Page Long Image keeps getting put at the end of the page!

Tags: floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)

I have some text, then, one page long image, followed by a page long table, and another page of text. What latex keeps doing is - it puts all the text together, and image and table at the end of the document. Where as, I want them as specified in the code, with the flow!

I have tried everything, h,t,p, ! etc..
kindly help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It would help if you added an example of the code you've tried so far, with information on the document class and LaTeX packages you employ.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you. Also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/

Comment: Try without using floats. `\includegraphics` and friends work perfectly well outside the `figure` environment.

Comment: Saying you tried "h,t,p..." suggests that you're using `figure` and `table`. These are "floats" so TeX decides where to put them. To make them go just where they are in your text, just include the graphics and use plain `tabular` for the table. That might lead to some strange page breaks you'll have to deal with. (... just as Count Zero says above.)

Comment: if a float (image or tabular) is too big for one page then it will be moved to the end of the chapter/section. Reduce the width by `\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{...}` to see what happens.

Comment: Using `{figure}[p]` normally works, but float placement for really small files is not perfect -- simply to less text for LaTeX to work on good placement. You could try to place the whole figure in an `\afterpage{\begin{figure}[p]..\end{figure}\clearpage}` (needs the `afterpage` package) and place that somewhere on the page before.